# 'dict' object has no attribute 'pk' when using Django bulk_create() function

Tags: python, django

I have a table `counters` with 2 fields: `date` and `value`.

I have a big list of objects which need to be inserted into table `counters`.
But using serializer.save() for every row in list, there will a lot of inserts and if i have a lot of data, it will take some time until it the data has finished inserting.

To solve this i looked into Django's documentation and i found that there is a function name `bulk_create` which can help me to insert into table a list of Objects in just 1 query.

Now, here's my code:

`models.py`:

```
class CounterFileData(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    value = models.FloatField()
```

`serializers.py`:

```
class CounterFileDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CounterFileData
        fields = ['date', 'value']
```

and the code where i use `bulk_create`:

```
objs = (CounterFileData(date=row.date, value=row.value) for row in parsed_data)

batch = list(parsed_data)
CounterFileData.objects.bulk_create(batch)
```

`row` has the following schema. For example:

```
{
    "date": "2018-12-31T22:00:00"
    "value": 9.23129792740622e-05
}
```

When i try to do that `CounterFileData.objects.bulk_create(batch)` i get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Can somebody tell me why it returns no attribute 'pk' ? I'm struggling with this thing some good hours and i still can't find a fix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You obtain the value in a dictionary for the corresponding key by *subscripting*, like:

```
objs = [CounterFileData(date=row['date'], value=row['value']) for row in parsed_data]
```

Furthermore you **passed `parsed_data` to the `list(..)` constructor**, whereas it **should be `objs`**. By using list comprehension however, we can omit that.

```
batch = [CounterFileData(date=row['date'], value=row['value']) for row in parsed_data]
CounterFileData.objects.bulk_create(batch)
```

Comment: @WolfEnergy: it would have been, since you never forced the generator for evaluation. You called `list(..)` on the wrong variable.

Comment: thank you, i was going by the documentation, and actually didn't spot the fact that i did that fault, never tried to think about that line .. And one more thing i would like to ask you.. bulk_create() uses .is_valid() by default on every data object or not ?

Comment: @WolfEnergy: no, in fact `model.save()` does not do validation. You can do it explicitly by calling `mymodel.full_clean()`.

Comment: since i can't use `save()` .. where should i place the `full_clean()` or which function to override ?

Comment: @WolfEnergy: you can iterate over the `objs` and call `.full_clean()` on all the elements before performing a `bulk_create`. Mind however that uniqness constraints can not be fully checked, since if a field is unique, and you insert two records with the same value for that field, before doing inserting there is no problem, and the objects are not a problem individually.

Comment: But, wouldn't this make all the process to be a lot slower ? And actually .. what uses bulk_create instead of save(), his own function of inserting into table ?

Comment: @WolfEnergy: yes indeed, but as with a lot of things, you can not have both :). The reason why Django's `.save()` does not validate properly is to save on queries. Certain things are checked at the db side (like uniqness), and then the insert will fail. Others, like `EmailValidation` are not, and thus it is possible that the insertion succeeds, but the email field is not valid.

Comment: Thank you a lot for clarifying me and for fast response, you really helped me understand how bulk_create() works, even better than the documentation.